# How do I add a new datamember to my custom checkboxlist?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

Does anybody know how to add a new data member to a subclass of checkedboxlist?

I have tried messing around with creating my own widgets, 
and have tried to get datagridview to behave the way I want it to.

the latter with no luck and the former I might not ever finish.

Here is a bindable checklistbox that I am trying to modify to fit my needs.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Design;

namespace WinformsTest.Controls
{

    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(CheckedListBox))]
    public class BindableCheckboxList : CheckedListBox
    {
        public BindableCheckboxList()
        {
            this.CheckOnClick = true;


        }

        [DefaultValue("")]
        [TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldConverter, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
        [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Data")]
        public new string DisplayMember
        {
            get
            {
                return base.DisplayMember;
            }
            set
            {
                base.DisplayMember = value;
            }
        }

        [DefaultValue("")]
        [TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldConverter, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
        [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Data")]
        public string CheckedMember
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        [DefaultValue("")]
        [TypeConverter("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldConverter, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
        [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberFieldEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Data")]
        public new string ValueMember
        {
            get
            {
                return base.ValueMember;
            }
            set
            {
                base.ValueMember = value;

            }
        }


        [DefaultValue("")]
        [AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
        [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Data")]
        public new object DataSource
        {
            get
            {
                return base.DataSource;
            }
            set
            {
                base.DataSource = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note I am trying to add a `CheckedMember`

I expect the checkedlistbox to update the checkboxes to checkedMember if the datasource is valid and bindable.

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I don't know how to update my checkboxes when the datasource is updated

Comment: Set it to null then back to the updated datasource?

Comment: I don't know when to update it though there is no event to know when a value has changed